akmod for Nvidia 470xx fails with Kernel 6.10.4 on Fedora 40
For some reason after a kernel update, my Nvidia kmod isn't being built anymore on Fedora 40.
I tried manually forcing building with:
akmods --force --rebuild

as root, but I'm getting the following error:
Building rpms failed; see /var/cache/akmods/nvidia-470xx/470.256.02-1-for-6.10.4-200.fc40.x86_64.failed.log for details
(the other kmods build fine)
The error log leads me to believe as if some library is missing or similar, however the file is rather long, so I'll attach it at the end of this post.
Basically I tried reinstalling anything to do with the kernel and nvidia drivers through dnf reinstall thinking something might've gone bad while upgrading. But it didn't solve the issue.
SELinux is deactivated.
I'm a little at a loss right now, and I'm not sure how to rectify the situation, other than downloading the drivers from nvidia's website and going through their - rather unpleasant - installation process...
akmods log file:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/polemon/2baa9cd5d26a581f730498d84db0b5b5/raw/9a2aeeebed252051c0eba2f1ce1c5856381192a4/gistfile1.txt
(had to upload it as a gist, because of stackexchange's size limitations. File is around 217kb in size)

If you are using the nvidia-470xx package from rpmfusion, it sounds like you could be experiencing this bug:  https://bugzilla.rpmfusion.org/show_bug.cgi?id=7020

I do! Thanks for the hint. I'll try the solutions discussed in the mailing list.
Is a similar problem known for the later akmods, or are they known to compile fine?
